# error: The argument type 'Uint8List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I'm trying to upload image from flutter web app to firebase storage but this error occur in the code.

> The argument type 'Uint8List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

How i can resolve this error?

Code is given below:

```
Future<void> pickImage() async
{
  FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

  if (result != null) {
    Uint8List? fileBytes =result.files.first.bytes;
    String fileName = result.files.first.name;
setState(() {
  fname=fileName;
});
    // Upload file
   await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images/$fileName').putData(fileBytes);
  var Downloadurl=await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images/$fileName').getDownloadURL();
 setState(() {
   imgUrl=Downloadurl;
 });
  }
}
```

I tried html input element and image picker package too, but cant solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure that the `fileBytes` is not `null`, you can cast it to `Uint8List` like this:

```
   await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images/$fileName').putData(fileBytes as Uint8List);
```

Comment: Error: [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.

Comment: how to change rules?

Comment: from yout firebase console

Comment: This is the same as doing `fileBytes!`, which is more concise.  Or, since `fileBytes` is a local variable, just check if `fileBytes != null` first, and `fileBytes` will be automatically be type-promoted if it's not `null`.

Comment: You have all right, thank you